# Print List in Java

Tags: java

I'm newbie in Java. I'm not sure why line `my2.print_list();` is printing only object `my2`. I want to print every time whole list of objects. I'm adding every object to list in constructor. I'm 90% sure that `for` loop in function `print_list` is good. The compiler shows no problems. I'll appreciate all help.

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
           rectangle my = new rectangle(5);
           rectangle my1 = new rectangle(3,6);
           rectangle my2 = new rectangle(10,7);

           System.out.println( my2.getCounter());
           my2.print_list(); ////////////////////<- described line

        }
    }
```

/// my class rectangle

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class rectangle {
        public static int counter =0;
        public int x;
        public int y;
        public List<rectangle> List = new ArrayList<rectangle>();

        public rectangle(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            System.out.println("Rec");
            List.add(this);
            counter++;
        }
        public rectangle(int x) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = x;
            System.out.println("Sqr");
            List.add(this);
            counter++;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "x->"+x+" y->"+y+" Field: "+(x*y);
        }

        public void print_list()
        {
            for(rectangle x : List)
            {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Each instance of `rectangle` has its own `List`, unless you make the `List` field `static`.

Comment: because rectangle is an object

Comment: I know you're relatively new to Java, but please stick to Java naming conventions.  Class names should always start with an upper-case letter, while variables and fields should always start with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 1):

Every instance of your class has its' own instance of `List`. Make it `static` if it should be shared (which is the only way your `List` will be populated). Also, please rename the variable `List` (it looks **exactly** like the interface `java.util.List`). Also, there's no reason to make it `public`.

```
private static List<rectangle> myList = new ArrayList<rectangle>();
```

And then change `print_list` like

```
public void printList()
{
    for(rectangle x : myList)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Also, the class name should be `Rectangle` (to follow Java naming conventions).

Comment: Re. `List` and `rectangle` yes please use the Java naming conventions.  They help others understand your code.  `print_list` should be `printList` too.

Comment: Thank you. If I want something that all objects will use I need to always make it static?For example "counter" in this class

Comment: Yes, `static` looks correct for `counter`.  Static variables are generally used a "global" variables in Java, something all classes/objects can see and use.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public List<rectangle> List = new ArrayList<rectangle>();
```

to

```
public static List<rectangle> List = new ArrayList<rectangle>();
```

So there's only one instance of List.